# How can I make my question meet MCVE guidelines?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, minimal-reproducible-example

Firstly, I want to make clear that I do think the guidelines regarding creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example are reasonable. They obviously help increase the quality of the site, and help make the site a better resource for newbies like me. Also, I have tried to write this post so that people with no knowledge of the language and library can understand, but there may still be some difficulty for those who don't know Java, or the graphical library that I had asked about, JavaFX.

I recently posted a question where both people who responded felt that it did not meet MCVE guidelines. I asked them why, but even with their responses, I'm still not sure how to meet their expectations. I have edited my question to try and meet those expectations, but I got a second flag for "unclear what you're asking" afterwards, and I would like to improve.

One mentioned that my example has to be runnable. Another said that I should have at most about 50 lines.

Again, I'm not an expert, but *as far as I know,* to get the simplest version of runnable example, a JavaFX user would have to put everything into JavaFX's required "Main" class and include many lines of code that JavaFX requires, but that may not be relevant to the specific error that you are having. Also, since JavaFX is a graphical library, the code may require external files that are not raw code, such as images or fonts. I don't know how to reduce my example down to about fifty lines and still have it runnable. Just displaying a single blank window takes about 25 lines, assuming you're spacing them out appropriately.

I have posted two code blocks of methods that were directly involved in creating and displaying the object I wanted to center in the middle of the window. These will not run by themselves.

I don't mind replacing those methods with a runnable example, but I am not sure if people would see it as meeting the "minimal" part of the MCVE guidelines. I continued asking both responders what they wanted, but they have stopped responding to me.

One of the responders posted an answer. I thanked them, but I told them that it didn't work for me.

*How can I improve my question and make it follow the MCVE guidelines adequately?*

**My Question:**

[Center a JavaFX ContextMenu in the middle of a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788456/center-a-javafx-contextmenu-in-the-middle-of-a-screen?noredirect=1#comment94440024_53788456)

Here is the most simplified runnable example I can create. It utilizes code from the answer I received. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make it produce the same problem. The object I wanted to center in the window, now won't appear at all.

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Main extends Application {
   Pane pane = getPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1600, 900);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * creates a Pane for creating a Scene
     * @return Pane
     */
   public Pane getPane() {
      // create a GridPane object
      GridPane grid = new GridPane();

      Text test = new Text("HERE");
      grid.add(test, 2, 2);

      // show/hide ContextMenu when keyboard escape key is pressed
      ContextMenu cm = createPopUpMenu();
      cm.setOnShowing(event -> {
         event.consume();
         cm.setAnchorX(cm.getAnchorX() - cm.getWidth() / 2.0);
         cm.setAnchorY(cm.getAnchorY() - cm.getHeight() / 2.0);
      });
      Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
      grid.setOnKeyReleased( event -> {
         if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
            cm.show(grid, bounds.getWidth() / 2.0, bounds.getHeight() / 2.0);
      });
      return grid;
   }

   /**
    * Creates a pop-up menu for saving, loading, and exiting the game
    * @return TextField 
    */
   public ContextMenu createPopUpMenu() {

      // create ContextMenu and it's MenuItem
      ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
      MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();

      // add image to MenuItem
      ImageView image = new ImageView("/PopUpMenu_Exit.png");
      menuItem.setGraphic(image);

      // add MenuItem to ContextMenu
      contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem);

      // When MenuItem is clicked, quit the game.
      menuItem.setOnAction( a -> {
         // quit the game
         Platform.exit();
         System.exit(0);
      });

      return contextMenu;
   }
}
```

Comment: The answers below are good.  One additional thing work mentioning: look at each line of code and ask yourself if the code is needed to demonstrate the problem.  If not, remove it.  (And if it is needed, is there a way to simplify?)

Comment: Minor point - I probably wouldn't bother including those imports, assuming they are 'obvious' from the context of it being a JavaFX question. If someone else's IDE would guess those imports when they paste your code, you probably don't need to include them in the question. If you really do need to, you could reduce them a little with wildcards (`import javafx.application.*;`). Similarly, you probably don't need the package declaration.

Comment: Oh, and you probably don't need most (possibly any) of those comments, particularly the ones that literally just describe the following line (eg `create a GridPane object`).

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the text of your question what the problem is - it took me a couple of reads to take in the bit about "it's still slightly off". Presumably the rectangle being "slightly off" is the meat of your question, so it wouldn't hurt to make that more prominent. Being a bit more specific about "slightly off" wouldn't hurt - is it always n pixels to the left? Does it vary based on screen size or resolution? One of the commenters in your question suggested a screenshot showing what's happening with highlights or something to show what you expect, that would definitely be good

Comment: A tangential observation; when someone replies with code or even a suggestion, it might not be the best idea to dismiss it with a simple "this doesn't seem to work for me". They have sunk in the time already and are most likely to respond further if you give accurate error messages or explain in detail what is not working or what you need further.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The MCVE guideline is, essentially, a trick intended to get you to do some debugging work on your own.

See, you're not supposed to just copy/paste your code into a code box and ask. In order for the example to be both "complete" enough for a user to run and "minimal" enough to be posted here, you have to go into your program with a metaphorical hatchet and start cutting out anything until the problem goes away. At which point it is no longer "verifiable", so you have to put that back and start cutting out other stuff. Eventually, you've cut down everything *except* the stuff that leads to the problem.

The thing is, 9-times-out-of-10 your hatcheting will tell you exactly where the problem is. Indeed, cutting out the unneeded bits is a common *debugging* tool. So ideally, once you get your example down to "minimal", "complete", and "verifiable"... the solution will present itself and you won't have to ask a question at all.

Basically, you meet the MCVE requirements by debugging the problem on your own until you have completely and totally isolated the problem in a short, reproducible test case.

Comment: I agree, sort of, 1+. The MCVE guidelines do make answering debugging questions much easier to do by off-loading the work of creating an unambiguous reproducing example on the person asking the question, and this is as it should be for a volunteer-staffed site. And yes, forcing the OP to isolate and expose the problem often allows them to see the source of the problem in all its nakedness and thus figure out a solution, but I see this as an added side benefit to the guidelines, not the primary purpose.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you both. I am still not completely sure what I should do to improve my question. Would you please let me know what you think?

Comment: Indeed, the side benefit has a side benefit.   It encourages the OP to improve their own debugging skills ... so that they don't *need* to ask Questions like that in the future.  After all, if the OP has the skills, they will be able to solve a debugging problem faster by doing it themselves ... which is to *their* advantage.

Comment: @LuminousNutria Another way to think about it is called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): explaining your problem to a rubber duck, working through your code line by line and explaining the purpose of each instruction. In so doing you tend to find your own mistake. I know that I've not-asked about 3 questions on SO because in the process of writing out the explanation for my question, I figured out my error.

Comment: I have so often thought I found the perfect unasked question, only to have the MCVE hatchet reveal the issue, and save me downvotes.

Comment: All this effort in getting people to submit an MCVE is so wasted because people do not understand this. We don't want questions with MCVEs, because debugging questions are useful only to the asker. We want more general questions: why when you do *X* does *Y* happen. Typically such questions need only 1 line of code.

Comment: @Raedwald: "*why when you do X does Y happen. Typically such questions need only 1 line of code.*" No, they don't. Any question of *substance* where a user is wondering why something happens due to some code will involve more than one line. Indeed, a one-liner is almost always "look it up in the docs" or "stop abusing C/C++'s rules about `++` and `--` in the middle of expressions." Neither of which is especially useful. Debugging questions are often useful to other people because many of them come from incomplete understanding or difficult APIs that cause others to have the same problem.

Answer (score 25):

> Here is the most simplified runnable example I can create. It utilizes code from the answer I received. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make it produce the same problem. The object I wanted to center in the window, now won't appear at all.

OK so what you have then is not an MCVE.  It fails on the "VE" part.  It is not an example of the problem that you want us to help you diagnose and fix.

How do you address that?  Well, basically, you have to figure out what is different about your real code (which is presumably too big to post) and your (not) MCVE ... that makes one exhibit the behavior, and the other not.  Alternatively, start again and attempt to produce your MCVE by *methodically* making small changes to simplify and reduce the size of your real code.

Yes ... it is hard work.  But that is programming.